# Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array

Tags: php

Boa tarde pessoal, estou tentando fazer um insert no banco de dados porém estou com um problema

Abaixo tem o metodo que esta com o erro junto da minha query para realizar o insert:

```
public function setData($data)
        {
            $this->setId($data['id']);
            $this->setNome($data['nome']);
            $this->setEmail($data['email']);
            $this->setSenha($data['senha']);  
        }
```

O erro esta na linha " $this->setData($results[0]);"

```
public function insert()
        {
            $sql = new Sql();

            $results = $sql->query("CALL sp_usuario_insert(:LOGIN, :EMAIL, :PASSWORD)", array(
                ":LOGIN"=>$this->getNome(),
                ":EMAIL"=>$this->getEmail(),
                ":PASSWORD"=>$this->getSenha()
            ));

            if (count($results) > 0) {
                $this->setData($results[0]);
            }

        }
```

Não estou conseguindo resolver.

Comment: Mostre o código da sua classe `Sql`, o problema deve estar lá.

Comment: A procedure retorna algum valor? parece estar faltando um `fetch()` aí.